# sprung into actions or sprung into action?

Tags: idioms

My question here is which is the correct phrase to use? *Action* with the S or without the S, and why?

Comment: Although *spring into action* is the most common usage,  *spring into actions* is not uncommon either. Both would be understood with no difference in meaning.

Comment: *Spring into action* is idiomatic: I disagree with @Noah that the alternative is in common use. This can be verified by checking a general reference such as OneLook: [ [spring into action](http://onelook.com/?w=spring+into+action&ls=a) ] vs. [ [spring into actions](http://onelook.com/?w=spring+into+actions&ls=a) ].

Comment: Unfortunately this question is easily answerable with a link to a general reference and is likely to be closed and ultimately deleted. See the [FAQ] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

**Without the /-s/**. Why? Because it's idiomatic English to say that someone *{sprang / sprung} into action* and not idiomatic to use *actions*. It's a standard cliché and, of course, an [idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spring+into+action).